# Python: Finding a line in a file works with windows but not linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, dictionary

I am attempting to create a piece of code that acts as a dictionary. This is part of a larger project but that seems to be working fine (for now...). I got it working on Windows 10, but once I swapped over to my Ubuntu machine (the end machine where I will run the program), it stopped working with the file I provided. Below is my code for this little bit of fun.

```
def commandDefineWord(request):         # NOT WORKING
    vanillaRequest = request.split(' ')
    clearRequest = (request.lower()).split(' ');

    if ((clearRequest[0] == "what") and (clearRequest[1] == "is") and (clearRequest[2] == "the")
        and (clearRequest[3] == "definition") and (clearRequest[4] == "for")):
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];      # Lots of extra word screening
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
    if (clearRequest[0] == "define"):
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
    if ((clearRequest[0] == "the") and (clearRequest[1] == "word")):
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];
        del clearRequest[0];
        del vanillaRequest[0];

    word = (vanillaRequest[0]).upper(); # define the word as a variable
    word = word.replace("?", "");       # remove ?'s
    dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r");   # Open dictionary file
    searchLines = dictionary.readlines();   # create a readable copy
    dictionary.close(); # Close file for safety

    found = False       # set as precaution to not finding word
    for i, line in enumerate(searchLines):  # enumerating all the lines while making them individual
        if (("%s\n" % word) == line):   # where is the bloody word?
            found = True;   # word is found
            print searchLines[i];   # print result
            i+=1;   # go to next line of definition
            while not searchLines[i].isupper(): # check to see if defintion end is reached
                searchLines[i] = searchLines[i].replace("\n", "");  # take away new lines
                print "\t %s" % searchLines[i]; # prints defintion
                i += 1;
    if found == False:
        print "Sorry, I could not find a definition for %s." % word
```

The vanillaRequest and clearRequest bits are used because (despite my best efforts) my brain told me to do it similar to other functions I wrote. This was not necessary for this particular function but in others it was essential I preserve the original request.

Giving a bit of probably important information, the dictionary text I am using is the "Webster's Unabridged Dictionary" from the Gutenberg Project. I apologize for not knowing how to upload this file (hopefully you can find it).

The problem seems (to me) to stem from "if (("%s\n" % word) == line):". I do not know what causes it to work on Windows but not Linux but I can provide a bit of useful information. I created a dummy dictionary with only these lines:

```
HELL

test definition

HECK
```

and it worked just as it did on Windows. I'm thinking the problem is with the file but I couldn't find one. Should I be missing any important, mystery solving information, tell me in the comments and I'll add it as soon as I can (if I can)!

If anyone could provide any insight at all it would be well appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. Yes the code is a bit clunky and a bit of an eyesore. I am not looking to change this as it works perfectly fine as is (besides the whole "Linux doesn't want to play nice with my files" dilemma.

Comment: I find it hard to follow your logic without a sample of input. As a quick guess, maybe your problem is whitespace related. For the line you are suspicious about maybe you should try:   if word.strip() == line.strip():   this is roughly the same check except it does not care about whitespace including newlines and carriage-returns at the start or end of word or line.  You probably are better off using the default split() on your strings rather than splitting on a single space like you do near the top of you function. But to be sure of anything, I think you need to provide a sample of the input.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire , a quick editing of the code and so far it works. I will test it more but I think you solved it! Would you happen to have any explanation behind this? I'm curious as to why this happened (and I bit sad that the fix was so simple and I hadn't thought of it). Thanks a ton!

Comment: [file.readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) "Read one entire line from the file. A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends with an incomplete line)."

Comment: [file.open](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) "On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written."

Comment: I don't know if it's the version you used, but [this version](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765.txt.utf-8) has ``\r\n`` line endings. Python 2 uses C `FILE` streams, and the Windows CRT implements [t]ext and [b]inary modes, with text mode being the default. Text mode converts the line endings to ``\n``. POSIX systems such as Linux generally only open files in binary mode. But in Python 2 you can get [U]niversal newlines mode if you open the file using `dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "rU")`.

Answer (score 0):

I just test a little, before `if (("%s\n" % word) == line):`codes, print `word` and `line` variables, word is always uppercase characters，while  line is not so. Maybe this is why `if` statements doesn't work.

Comment: The word is always uppercase before the definition in the dictionary file. The line is not because some lines are purely definition. What the statement does is go through and find an exact match for the "word" variable. This is the beginning of the definition.